# Does hot reloading works only when change the XAML in Jet Brains Rider IDE (physical device case)?

Tags: xamarin, rider, jetbrains-rider

### Experiment flow

Start the debugging of application:

[image]

Check the Debug Output:

[image]

On change of any XAML file:

```
[1]HotReloadAgent: Reload request for XamarinExploring: 'Views\PeopleListPage.xaml'
[1]HotReloadAgent: Reload view of type 'XamarinExploring.Views.PeopleListPage'...
```

On change VuewModel C# file:

```
[1]HotReloadAgent: Reload request for XamarinExploring: 'ViewModels\PeopleListViewModel.cs'
[1]HotReloadAgent: There is no tracked views, nothing to reload.
All registered tracked views:
    XamarinExploring: Views/PeopleListPage.xaml
    XamarinExploring: Views/PersonDetailsPage.xaml
```

I can't understand is the changing of the logic is not enough reson to reload the application.

Comment: First of all you have to use `Debug` action, not run. And read debug output carefully, XAML hot reload writes everything there

Comment: @xtmq Thank you for the hint. I have changed my question to more narrow one.

Comment: HotReload works only with XAML pages. Not with c# files. HotReload for .net files is not implemented yet for xamarin in Rider

Comment: @xtmq It is only Rider's issue? What about Visual Studio?